# Easiest way to add 3 dot pop up menu AppBar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

1. I want a 3 dot popup menu button in the app bar of my app
2. It must be a clickable one [navigate to other widgets,pages]
3. Please tell how to add a pop up menu button in  a simpler way

Answer (score 154):

The simplistic way is undoubtedly to avoid auxiliary classes. 
As of Dart 2.2 with the use of set literals, we can place the map of menu items in the app bar directly

```
 appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Homepage'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          PopupMenuButton<String>(
            onSelected: handleClick,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
              return {'Logout', 'Settings'}.map((String choice) {
                return PopupMenuItem<String>(
                  value: choice,
                  child: Text(choice),
                );
              }).toList();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

and handle click with value of Item text in method

```
void handleClick(String value) {
    switch (value) {
      case 'Logout':
        break;
      case 'Settings':
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: so that the three points are displayed in a stack you can wrap using RotateBox. EJ: RotatedBox(
              quarterTurns: 1,
              child: PopupMenuButton<String>(...)
)

Comment: Regarding `RotatedBox` - very helpful, Thanks.  In testing so far I see it is only necessary for iOS.

Comment: @Ondrej How to use it if some menu options has some children menu options?

Comment: @ManuelOrtiz or you can add an icon to `PopupMenuButton` like: `icon: const Icon(Icons.more_vert_rounded),`. That's cross-platform.

Answer (score 19):

The same without the warning message and localization:

```
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Homepage'),
    actions: <Widget>[
      PopupMenuButton<int>(
          onSelected: (item) => handleClick(item),
          itemBuilder: (context) => [
            PopupMenuItem<int>(value: 0, child: Text('Logout')),
            PopupMenuItem<int>(value: 1, child: Text('Settings')),
          ],
        ),
    ],
  ),


void handleClick(int item) {
  switch (item) {
    case 0:
      break;
    case 1:
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:settings_button/Constants.dart';
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new MaterialApp(
            title: 'Flutter Demo',
            theme: new ThemeData(
                primarySwatch: Colors.blue,)
            ,
            home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),);
    }

}
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    MyHomePage({
        Key key, this.title
    })

        : super(key: key);
    final String title;
    @override
    _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
                title: new Text(widget.title),
                actions: <Widget>[
                    PopupMenuButton<String>(
                        onSelected: choiceAction,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context){
                            return Constants.choices.map((String choice){
                                return PopupMenuItem<String>(
                                    value: choice,
                                    child: Text(choice),);
                            })
                                .toList();
                        }
                        ,)]
                ,)
            ,
            body: new Center(
                child: new Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                        new Text(
                            'Body',)
                        ,]
                    ,)
                ,)
            ,);
    }

    void choiceAction(String choice){
        if(choice == Constants.Settings){
            print('Settings');
        }
        else if(choice == Constants.Subscribe){
            print('Subscribe');
        }
        else if(choice == Constants.SignOut){
            print('SignOut');
        }
    }

}
```

Constants.dart

```
class Constants{
  static const String fund = 'Fund';
//  static const String Settings = 'Settings';
  static const String SignOut = 'Sign out';

  static const List<String> choices = <String>[
    fund,`enter code here`
    SignOut
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 8):

you can use this example from flutter docs :

https://flutter.dev/docs/catalog/samples/basic-app-bar

```dart
// Copyright 2017 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// This app is a stateful, it tracks the user's current choice.
class BasicAppBarSample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BasicAppBarSampleState createState() => _BasicAppBarSampleState();
}

class _BasicAppBarSampleState extends State<BasicAppBarSample> {
  Choice _selectedChoice = choices[0]; // The app's "state".

  void _select(Choice choice) {
    // Causes the app to rebuild with the new _selectedChoice.
    setState(() {
      _selectedChoice = choice;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Basic AppBar'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            // action button
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(choices[0].icon),
              onPressed: () {
                _select(choices[0]);
              },
            ),
            // action button
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(choices[1].icon),
              onPressed: () {
                _select(choices[1]);
              },
            ),
            // overflow menu
            PopupMenuButton<Choice>(
              onSelected: _select,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                return choices.skip(2).map((Choice choice) {
                  return PopupMenuItem<Choice>(
                    value: choice,
                    child: Text(choice.title),
                  );
                }).toList();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: ChoiceCard(choice: _selectedChoice),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Choice {
  const Choice({this.title, this.icon});

  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
}

const List<Choice> choices = const <Choice>[
  const Choice(title: 'Car', icon: Icons.directions_car),
  const Choice(title: 'Bicycle', icon: Icons.directions_bike),
  const Choice(title: 'Boat', icon: Icons.directions_boat),
  const Choice(title: 'Bus', icon: Icons.directions_bus),
  const Choice(title: 'Train', icon: Icons.directions_railway),
  const Choice(title: 'Walk', icon: Icons.directions_walk),
];

class ChoiceCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChoiceCard({Key key, this.choice}) : super(key: key);

  final Choice choice;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextStyle textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1;
    return Card(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(choice.icon, size: 128.0, color: textStyle.color),
            Text(choice.title, style: textStyle),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(BasicAppBarSample());
}
```

Comment: im curious. is this the only way? the animation when displayed is not the same as in android native.

Comment: @chitgoks that's probably because Flutter uses it's own components, not the native View elements that Android has.

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way I've found to add the "overflow" menu, and pop-up menu buttons in general, is to do the following:

```dart
PopupMenuButton<void Function()>(
  itemBuilder: (context) {
    return [
      PopupMenuItem(
        value: () => debugPrint('Item 1 hit'),
        child: const Text('Item 1'),
      ),
      PopupMenuItem(
        value: () => debugPrint('Item 2 hit'),
        child: const Text('Item 2'),
      ),
    ];
  },
  onSelected: (fn) => fn(),
);
```

By using a `Function` for the popup menu's value, you avoid an `onSelected` function which uses a `switch` or `if` statement. It also eliminates item coupling between the `itemBuilder` and  `onSelected` functions - i.e., your `onSelected` doesn't need to know what the menu items are or what order they're in.

Comment: this is the best answer IMHO, and an even more generic approach is to use `PopupMenuButton<void Function(BuildContext context)>(....)`

Answer (score 5):

```
PopupMenuButton<int>(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuItem<int>>[
          new PopupMenuItem<int>(
              value: 1, child: new Text('Item One')),
          new PopupMenuItem<int>(
              value: 2, child: new Text('Item Two')),
          new PopupMenuItem<int>(
              value: 3, child: new Text('Item Three')),
          new PopupMenuItem<int>(
              value: 4, child: new Text('I am Item Four'))
        ],
        onSelected: (int value) {
          setState(() { _value = value; });
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

inside actions list

```
      PopupMenuButton(onSelected: menuAction, itemBuilder: (BuildContext itemBuilder) => {'Opt 1', 'Opt 2'}.map((value) => PopupMenuItem(child: Text(value), value: value,)).toList())
```

method to handle Item Click

```
  void menuAction(String value) {
   switch (value) {  
    case 'Opt 1':
     print('Hello');
     break;
  }
}
```